# delete orphan test suite

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am not able to delete orphan test suite (Test suite without any parent Test Plan).

I migrated Test Plan and Test suites using vstssyncmigrator tool. There is issue with Azure DevOps identifying the migrated objects, i.e. Test Plan. When I access test plan from Test Plans options, it firstly shows error but after some time it creates root test suite automatically and the error goes away.

So I want to delete the migrated test suites which are not associated with any Test Plan. Is there any way to achieve this?

I check the microsoft restapi and noticed that we need to have test plan id to delete rest suite.

Any suggestions to clean up this test suite garbage? Any suggestions / help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you said in this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/672239/cannot-delete-orphan-testsuite.html), you can find test suites in the query.You can try to delete these test suites from the query to see if this is work.

[image]